# problema con rutas en laravel con xampp

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6

me encuentro aprendiendo laravel, a penas empece , estoy viendo tutoriales y resulta que una ruta esta asi

```
<li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
```

osea toda la ruta de mi proyecto

```
http://localhost/laravel/Miproyecto/public/about
```

pero resulta que al ejecutarla en el navegador me sale asi

```
/about
```

entonces no la encuentra no se por que se desaparece el resto de laruta si en el video sigue intacta por ejemplo para un hombre

```
<li><a href="/">home</a></li>
```

que seria esto

```
http://localhost/laravel/Miproyecto/public/
```

se me desaparece la ruta y en la url del navegador me queda asi /  y por ende no encuentra nada. no se por que sucedera, al tutor del video no le pasa.

Comment: Muestranos tu archivo de rutas

Comment: para no entrar en tanto problema, que al final tendras quere solver cuando migres a tiempo real te sugiero confirurarun virtualhost directo sobre la carpeta principal public...

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que, si estas trabajando con laravel, este framework tiene su propio sistema de rutas que debe ser usada, es decir, que tienes que declararlas en un archivo la cual mapeara y trabajara para que sean validas. <s>(Si alguien que usa Laravel ve esto me va a matar por dar una explicación muy coloquial xD)</s>

Para ello, vamos al archivo de rutas que usa laravel, `web.php`
dentro de el, habrá un único método, el cual nos renderiza la vista de inicio

```
Route::get('/', function(){
  return view('welcome');
});
```

Donde nos damos cuenta que, el archivo va a las vistas y renderiza el archivo que se llama `welcome.blade.php`

Una vez comprendido, toca ver un ejemplo, si tienes dos rutas debes agregarlas en tu archivo web. Y para ello, vamos a crear una vista llamada home que tenga unos links

La vista `home.blade.php` tendra agregado unos links

```
<html>
  <head>Titulo dummy</head>

  <body>
    <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Inicio</a>
    <a href="{{ url('/whois') }}">Quienes somos</a>
    <a href="{{ url('/contact') }}">Contacto</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Dentro de tu archivo web.php debes declarar esto en unas funciones, para ello quedaria de la siguiente manera:
El archivo `web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function(){
  return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', function(){
  return view('home');
});

Route::get('/whois', function(){
  return view('about');
});

Route::get('/contact', function(){
  return view('contact');
});
```

Para que esto funcione, debes crear las plantillas en tu carpeta views, y con el archivo `web.php` seran referenciadas, recuerda que el nombre de la plantilla debe ser igual al nombre del que pusiste en `return view('nombreplantilla')`.

Comment: el problema de lo que le estas diciendo que use, esque no es portable cuando vaya am servidir de produccion... es mas facil que defina un virtual host en xampp sobre su directorio raiz... que sera lo mismo cuando vaye a producciin y se ahorra todo el reververo de las rutas.... quedanfo igual funcionales...